# Lua table convert

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am new to lua, I have a table `foo` and I want to convert it to `bar` like following：

```
foo:{key1,value2,key2,value2} ==> bar:{key1=value1,key2=value2}
```

Does lua have a built-in method to do that ?

Comment: How do you differentiate between a key and value?

Comment: @hjpotter92 The odd entry is a key and the even entry is a value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your [recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922942/lua-table-convert?noredirect=1#comment29646204_19922942), try this:

```
local bar, iMax = {}, #foo
for i = 1, iMax, 2 do
    bar[foo[i]] = foo[i + 1]
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one solution using an iterator:

```
function two(t)
    local i = -1
    return function() i = i + 2; return t[i], t[i + 1] end
end
```

Then you can use the iterator like this:

```
local bar = {}
for k, v in two(foo) do
    bar[k] = v
end
```

Note that it should be `bar = {[key1]=value1, [key2]=value2}`. In your example, `{key1=value1,key2=value2}` is a syntax sugar for string keys.